# Calculating Day over Day % Change

Tags: business-objects

I am building a report with date on my x axis and ads on my Y axis.

the body contains a daily count of a measure and I'd like to calculate the percent change from day to day, but I am having difficulty building this variable. report looks like row below.

```
date date   date
```

xyz 10   5      10

I have read a lot about current date and relevant date function but can't get it to work properly. I have tried to build out layers of variables, such as Yesterday's count and 2 days ago count and then combine these in a variable to calculate the % Change.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you using, WebI, DeskI, something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the axes so date is on x axis you should be able to use the Previous formula. You'd basically have the `% change` formula, referencing the previous row:

```
% change formula as a decimal: (y2-y1)/y1
% change formula as a percentage: ((y2-y1)/y1)*100
```

Your formula:

```
=(([Value]-Previous([Value]))/Previous([Value]))*100
```